# Codeigniter 2 - internationalization without segment in the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I have created a new portal in 5 language using the library: internationalization i18n

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n

Works fine, but the in the url there is ever the language segment (en, fr, de, ru ecc)
example: http://www.abcdefg.com/fr/ http://www.abcdefg.com/en/

I would like call my homepage without the segment; How can I do?

example http://www.abcdefg.com (the default language is EN)

Thanks

Comment: Once you decide language parameter `en` for client, store it in PHP session.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have the URL with NO lang code display the english version without adding the en/ to URI? Sounds like htaccess work